# Allocate 1 Dimension array with cudaMallocPitch and then copy to device with cudaMemcpy2D 3

Tags: c++, matrix, cuda, gpu, sparse-matrix

I have read this post [Allocate 2D array with cudaMallocPitch and copying with cudaMemcpy2D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991667/allocate-2d-array-with-cudamallocpitch-and-copying-with-cudamemcpy2d) among many others including NVIDIA docs and I can't get cudaMallocPitch to work together with cudaMemcpy2D.

I need to copy a very big matrix in an array format (Matrix[width*height]) along with a simple array to perform Matrix * vector operations. It is not optional for me to use cudaMallocPitch in order to avoid conflicts and have a better performance.

So, I started by just trying to copy the matrix (vector in my case) to the device and check if it was correctly copied but my code does not print anything. If I use cudaMalloc and cudaMemcpy everything works fine. But I do not know what to do with cudaMallocPitch and cudaMemcpy2D.

What can I do to fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
__global__ void kernel(size_t mpitch, double * A, int N)
{
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    while (idx < N)
    {
        double e = *(double *)(((char *) A + idx * mpitch) + N);
        printf("(%f)", e);
    }
}
int main()
{
    int N = 1500;
    double * A  = new double[N], * d_A;
    size_t pitch;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        A[i] = i;
    }
    cudaMallocPitch(&d_A, &pitch,  sizeof(double) * N, 1);
    cudaMemcpy2D(d_A, pitch, A, N * sizeof(double), sizeof(double) * N, 1, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    unsigned int blocksize = 1024;
    unsigned int nblocks = (N + blocksize - 1) / blocksize;
    kernel <<<nblocks, blocksize>>>(pitch, d_A, N);
    cudaFree(d_A);
    delete [] A;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I guess it should be `kernel(size_t mpitch, double* A, int N)`, right?

Comment: alright, I was wrong with the address calculation; however you should still use error checking and check the indices you are calculating as they are producing out out bound accesses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error checking can make a big difference in debugging. You should always use it before coming here.

It wasn't clear if you wanted a row or column vector i.e. a matrix of [1xN] or [Nx1]

I've added an explanation on Talomnies suggestion, but first the 'working slabs of code'

Here's [Nx1]

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda.h>

using namespace std;

__global__ void kernel(size_t mpitch, double * A, int N)
{
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if(idx>=N) return;
    double e = *(double *)(((char *) A + idx * mpitch));
    printf("(%f)", e);

}
int main()
{
    int N = 15;
    double * A  = new double[N], * d_A;
    size_t pitch;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        A[i] = i;
    }

    cudaError_t err = cudaMallocPitch(&d_A, &pitch, sizeof(double), N);
    if(err!=cudaSuccess) cout<<"err0:"<<cudaGetErrorString(err)<<endl;

    err = cudaMemcpy2D(d_A, pitch, A, sizeof(double), sizeof(double), N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if(err!=cudaSuccess) cout<<"err1:"<<cudaGetErrorString(err)<<endl;

    unsigned int blocksize = 1024;
    unsigned int nblocks = (N + blocksize - 1) / blocksize;
    kernel <<<nblocks, blocksize>>>(pitch, d_A, N);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    err = cudaGetLastError();
    if(err!=cudaSuccess) cout<<"err2:"<<cudaGetErrorString(err)<<endl;

    cudaFree(d_A);
    delete [] A;
    return 0;
}
```

[1xN]:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda.h>

using namespace std;

__global__ void kernel(size_t mpitch, double * A, int N)
{
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if(idx>=N) return;
    int row=0;//only one row

    double *row_ptr = (double *)( (char *) (A + mpitch * row) );
    double e = row_ptr[idx];
    printf("(%f)", e);

}
int main()
{
    int N = 15;
    double * A  = new double[N], * d_A;
    size_t pitch;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        A[i] = i;
    }

    cudaError_t err = cudaMallocPitch(&d_A, &pitch, sizeof(double)*N, 1);
    if(err!=cudaSuccess) cout<<"err0:"<<cudaGetErrorString(err)<<endl;

    err = cudaMemcpy2D(d_A, pitch, A, sizeof(double)*N, sizeof(double)*N, 1, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if(err!=cudaSuccess) cout<<"err1:"<<cudaGetErrorString(err)<<endl;

    unsigned int blocksize = 1024;
    unsigned int nblocks = (N + blocksize - 1) / blocksize;
    kernel <<<nblocks, blocksize>>>(pitch, d_A, N);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    err = cudaGetLastError();
    if(err!=cudaSuccess) cout<<"err2:"<<cudaGetErrorString(err)<<endl;

    cudaFree(d_A);
    delete [] A;
    return 0;
}
```

**Explanation**

Firslty, Error Handling:

Considering how easy error handling is in CUDA there isn't a good excuse not to put it in.

```
cudaError_t err = cudaMallocPitch(&d_A, &pitch, sizeof(double)*N, 1);
if(err!=cudaSuccess) cout<<"err0:"<<cudaGetErrorString(err)<<endl;
```

Second, you didn't specify if you wanted a column vector or a row vector. Since a row vector is simply a 1-D array in linear memory and you don't need pitched memory to do that, I will assume for this explanation that you meant a column vector.

The reoccurring problem you were having was "misaligned address" in the kernel. This indicates that the problem is book-keeping, so lets walk through the three major steps of handling an aligned 2D array (even though our arrays will be either a column or row vector).

**Allocating**:
Your allocation was written out as

```
cudaMallocPitch(&d_A, &pitch,  sizeof(double) * N, 1);
```

This is correct for the row vector as the API is `cudaMallocPitch(void*** pointer, size_t* pitch_return, size_t row_width_in_bytes, size_t count_of_rows)` However if we would like to do a column vector correct call is

```
cudaMallocPitch(&d_A, &pitch, sizeof(double), N);
```

**Accessing**:
For accessing you were mixing up accessing a row, and accessing an element in the row.

```
double e = *(double *)(((char *) A + idx * mpitch) + N);
```

Once again stick to the documentation. The API documentation for cudaMallocPitch includes

```
T* pElement = (T*)((char*)BaseAddress + Row * pitch) + Column;
```

for us this translates into

```
int column=0;
double element=(double*) ((char*)A + idx * mpitch) + column;
```

I've used `column = 0` for completeness since we do not have more than one column.

**Copying**:

```
cudaMemcpy2D(d_A, pitch, A, N * sizeof(double), sizeof(double) * N, 1, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

For this case this is correct. API for `cudaMemcpy2D` is

```
cudaMemcpy2D(void* destination, size_t pitch_from_mallocPitch, const void* source, size_t source_pitch_bytes, size_t src_width_in_bytes, size_t src_rows_count, enum type_of_xfer);
```

Comment: Yeah, there you go ;)

Comment: I have got to say I am not a fan of this sort of answer. It just a slab of working code which completely fails to explain what was wrong, why it was wrong, and what is required to fix it. When the next person with a similar problem finds this by searxh, they are going to be forced to diff the OP's code and the versions in this answer to see what the changes were, and then try and understand them by themselves. Mostly unhelpful.

Comment: I always thought that if a picture was worth a thousand words a short compileable example focused on the topic must be worth two thousand. Most of the way I learned more complex problems was to create or find examples like this and slowly convert it to my application. However, I'm sure you're right that it would be useful to some to have a `slab of text` explaining the more important details.